# Jump to another EditText Field After Typing while entering OTP

Tags: android, firebase

I'm currently implementing one time password receiver. After receiving otp from firebase and entering into the textfield, I need to press "Next" on keyboard in order to go another EditText field and I want it automatically move to another field. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen on text change on each edittext:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

@Override    
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
  int count, int after) {
}

@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
  int before, int count) {
   if(s.length() != 0)
     nextEdittext.requestFocus();
 }
});
```

Do this for all edittexts and focus on next one.

Comment: <EditText
android:id="@+id/otpfield_1"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:backgroundTint="@color/main_color"
android:maxLines="1"
android:focusable="true"
android:digits="0123456789"
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/otpfield_2"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="1"
android:textColor="@color/main_color"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

Comment: I put this but I still need to press "Next" in order to go to another field.

Comment: So you need automatically focus next edittext after input number ?

Comment: Yes . I believe there is a code in java like if the input >1 it should go to another field.